# Python3. Add few values to existing key

Tags: python, dictionary

I know there is a lot of information about this subject, but I'm really stuck with this problem.

I have a dictionary loaded from a file:

```
datastore = json.load(f)    
print(datastore)
{"a": "999", "b": "345"}
```

Now, I need to add more values to the existing key.

But instead I receive an error:

> `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
if key in datastore:
    temp = []
    [temp.extend([k, v]) for k, v in datastore.items()]
    print(temp)
    print(type(temp))
    i = temp.index(key)
    print(i)
    temp[i].append(value)
    print(temp)
```

and:

```
if key in datastore:
    datastore.setdefault(key, [])
    datastore[key].append(value)
```

Result is the same:

> `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Please help!

Full code below:

```
import os
import json
import argparse
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 3:

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--key")
  parser.add_argument("--val")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  key = args.key
  value = args.val

  storage = {}
  storage[key] = value

  if os.path.exists('storage_file'):
    with open('storage_file', 'r') as f:
      datastore = json.load(f)
      if key in datastore:
        datastore.setdefault(key, [])
        datastore[key].append(value)
      else:
        datastore.update({key: value})
      with open('storage_file', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(datastore, f)
  else:
    with open('storage_file', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(storage, f)

else:
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--key", action="store")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  key = args.key

  with open('storage_file', 'r') as f:
    datastore = json.load(f)
    print(datastore.get(key))
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect `datastore` to be after you've added values to existing keys?

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not work, reason see comments:

```
if os.path.exists('storage_file'):
   with open('storage_file', 'r') as f:
     datastore = json.load(f)
     if key in datastore:
       datastore.setdefault(key, [])   # key already exists, you just checked it, so it  
       datastore[key].append(value)    # will not create [], tries append to existing data
     else:
       datastore.update({key: value})
     with open('storage_file', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(datastore, f)
```

You can try to fix it with:

```
if os.path.exists('storage_file'):
   with open('storage_file', 'r') as f:
     datastore = json.load(f)
     if key in datastore:
       val = datastore[key]
       if type(val) == str:               # check if it is a string / if you use other
         datastore[key] = [ val ]         # types you need to check if not them as well
       datastore[key].append(value) 
     else:
       datastore.setdefault(key, [ value ])    # create default [] of value

     with open('storage_file', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(datastore, f)
```

(Disclaimer: Code not executed, may contain typos, tell me, I'll fix)

Reads:

- [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
- [type()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type)

You check if a *key* that you parsed from the commandline was already stored into the json-file that load as `datastore`. If you have a file that contains a string for a certain key, loadign it will always recreate it as string.

Your code checks if a *key* is already in `datastore` - if so the *new* code reads the value into `val`. Then it checks if `val` is of type `str` - if so it replaces the value in `datastore` for `key` with a list containing `val`. Then it appends the new parameter that you parsed from the commandline.

In case the *key* is **not** in the dictionary, it creates the entry in `datastore` directly as list, using the just parsed value as defaultvalue inside the list.

Then all is stored back and replaces the current file.

Comment: Patrick, thank you that is very helpful. And i understand the picture its self, but i missing the magic that happens here:`val = datastore[key] #here i take existing value to val variable - ok
       if type(val) == str:  #doing check - ok            
         datastore[key] = [ val ]   # magic here!      
       datastore[key].append(value)` - #and now that is doing append without error! magic again!

Comment: When you load the datastore the former value you saved as string is restored as string in datastore. I check if it is a string. if so I save it as list.  So the value is now no longer a string but a list containing a string. and lists have got the `.append()` method to put more things into the list. Thats why it works.. its the same as when you use `sillyExample = [ 1, 2, 3]` or `a=1` + `b=1` + `c=1` + `sillyAgain = [ a,b,c]` - you store the value of a variable inside a list. You changed the type of the value that is stored under that key from "string" to "list of strings". No magic involved.